# Why does typescript not see my function?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, angular, typescript

I have the following Listener that is in a onInit method:

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(this.map, 'click', function(event) {
        console.log(event.latLng);
        var lt = event.latLng.lat;
        var ln = event.latLng.lng;
        console.log(lt());
        console.log(ln());
        this.onStoreMarker(lt(),ln());
    });
```

Outside I have a method which is called when the event is triggered, Angular2 compiles this fine but when I try activate the event by clicking when running the app I get a error saying

> Uncaught TypeError: this.onStoreMarker is not a function

```
 onStoreMarker(lt: number,ln: number) {
        var newStore = prompt("Please enter your store name", "Store Name");
        var location = {lat: lt, lng: ln};
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: location, 
            map: this.map,
            title: newStore,
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
google.maps.event.addListener(this.map, 'click', function(event) {
```

with

```
google.maps.event.addListener(this.map, 'click', (event)=> {
```

your `this` is not refering to your component.

Alternatively, the old js way:

```
var self = this; // store this in a variable to use it later
google.maps.event.addListener(this.map, 'click', function(event) {
        console.log(event.latLng);
        var lt = event.latLng.lat;
        var ln = event.latLng.lng;
        console.log(lt());
        console.log(ln());
        self.onStoreMarker(lt(),ln()); // <-- use it later
    });
```

I suggest you to read this for a more in-depth answer: [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback/20279485#20279485)